# Unable to add particular view through Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database out of which I am unable to add a view in to the Visual Studio and Entity Framework.

Can you please me out regarding what can be the issue.

Below is the error:

> Error 6013: The table/view 'dbo.EmpDtls_vw1' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

Comment: I think the message is very clear. Add a primary key to your table/model.

Comment: I am unable to add primary key to a view

Answer (score 0):

You view doesn't have a key column. If you use net core , try to add this code to your dbcontext

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<EmpDtls>()
            .HasNoKey()
            .ToView("dbo.EmpDtls_vw1");
    }
```

or you can try this code if you use the attributes

```
 [Keyless]
public class EmpDtls
{
   .......
}
```